# PHP empty array definition with starting or ending comma

Tags: php, arrays, definition

So I've come accross these on PHP8 code from my office (simplified) :

```
[, $x] = $y;
```

I also saw the other way

```
[$x, ] = $y;
```

What would these do? If I do that in a sandbox and assign random values to $y beforehand, I don't get anything for $x. I know that it is not badcode, as PHPStorm valids it.

I've tried searching for it, but every search engines including Stackoverflow will ignore commas or [], so I can't get my answer.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the values of $x and $y after?

Comment: What values did you give to `$y`? It has to be an array so that destructuring assignment will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$array = [10, 20, 30];

[$x, ] = $array;

echo $x;  // Output: 10

[, $x] = $array;

echo $x;  // Output: 20

[2 => $x] = $array;

echo $x;  // Output: 30
```

It's called [array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.destructuring).

Comment: Thx, figured it was something that simple, but couldn't get my hand on googling it as I didn't know the term.

Answer (score 5):

This is destructuring assignment. The variables in the array on the left are assigned from the corresponding elements of the array on the right. It's equivalent to the old [`list()` assignment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

You can use commas with no variable before/after to indicate elements of the array that are skipped when assigning. Thus:

```
[, $x] = $y;
```

is equivalent to

```
$x = $y[1];
```

and

```
[$x, ] = $y;
```

is equivalent to

```
$x = $y[0];
```

You wouldn't usually use this syntax for assigning a single variable, it's mostly useful for assigning multiple variables:

```
[$a, $b, , $c] = $y;
```

which is a shortcut for

```
$a = $y[0];
$b = $y[1];
$c = $y[3];
```

There's no need for the comma at the end of the list, but you might include them for the same reason you would include a comma in an array literal: it makes it easier to add additional elements (especially when you write them one per line).

Comment: This only works with sequential numerical indexes, right?

Comment: Yes. Unlike array literals, you can't mix keyed and unkeyed array entries in the assignment target.

Comment: Well, they did exactly that at my job, for only one $x, so I am still trying to figure why write [$x, ] = $y; instead of $x = $y[0];

Comment: It might just be for consistency.